# Speed up matrix formatting

Tags: r, performance, matrix, formatting

I need to convert a large matrix to specific format for use with libsvm. The format consists starting each row with a label (either 1 or -1) followed by 0:*row_number* and the row values as 1:*value_at_row_number_1st_column*

The simple approach given below is too slow,

```
require(microbenchmark) 
nR = 100; nC = 500
kMat = matrix(runif(nR*nC), nrow=nR)
yLab = sample(c(1, -1), nR, replace = T)

# Simple method
met1 = function() {
  lines = c()
  for(ix in 1:nrow(kMat))
    lines = c(lines, 
          paste(yLab[ix],
                paste0("0:", ix),
                paste0(1:ncol(kMat), ":", kMat[ix, ], collapse=" ")))
  lines
}
```

I have also made a ~50% faster version (although way uglier),

```
# Sprintf
met2 = function() {
  fmt = c("%i", "0:%i", paste0(1:ncol(kMat), ":%f")) 
  kMat = cbind(yLab, 1:nrow(kMat), kMat)
  # Unfortunately sprintf cannot handle more than 100 arguments
  splts = lapply(seq(1, length(fmt), 99L),
                 function(ix) {
                   r = ix:min(ncol(kMat), ix+98L)
                   list(range = r, fmt = list(paste(fmt[r], collapse =     " ")) )
             })
  lines = sapply(1:nrow(kMat),
                 function(ix) {
                   Reduce(function(a, b) sprintf("%s %s", a, b), 
                          sapply(splts, 
                                 function(s){
                                   do.call(sprintf, c(s$fmt, kMat[ix, s$range]))
                                 }),
                          "")
                 })
  lines
}
print(microbenchmark(met1(), met2())) 

Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 met1() 85.83051 88.00289 92.01948 88.61834 90.31918 175.3362   100
 met2() 44.81729 45.61020 56.12835 54.75313 56.65249 108.7218   100
```

Is there a faster (or a neater) way to handle this formatting?

Comment: 90 milliseconds is too slow?

Comment: This was only a test sample, I will be working on much larger sets also repeating the operation multiple times

Comment: I'm not optimistic that you can do much better with R. You might need to switch to a different language.

Answer (score 0):

This is both shorter and faster.  It seems that the conversion done by `sprintf` from `double` to `character` is faster than the implicit `as.character` and the `stringi::stri_join` gives a bit of speed up over `paste` and `paste0`.  I also tried variations in which the transpose was eliminated but the code below was faster.

```
library(stringi)

met3 <- function() {   
    s <- stri_join("0:", seq_len(nC), " ", sprintf("%f", t(kMat)))
    m <- matrix(s, nC)
    stri_join(yLab, apply(m, 2, stri_join, collapse = " "), sep = " ")
}
```

giving:

```
> microbenchmark(met3(), met2(), times = 10)
Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 met3() 236.6127 255.1396 264.7797 256.6331 292.1037 296.6377    10
 met2() 307.6371 322.1467 354.7281 332.0041 388.2474 464.2259    10
```

Comment: Note that this was revised a few times and it is now faster than the code in the question.

Comment: Hmmh, your approach did not improve speed in my test.. A best it was equal to 'met2'

Comment: I am using "R Under development (unstable) (2016-12-04 r71726)"
on a Windows 10 laptop.  Although it did not help when I tried it since you are getting different timings you could try eliminating the transpose.